# Dropping trailing `.0` from float without modifying the precision with fstrings

Tags: python

How can I format a float with fstrings such that the output doesn't change, unless there is a trailing `.0`, then simply drop it ?

I am asking because most answers simply tell us to use the `g` [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) but that is not the correct answer. When using the `g` if the number gets too large, the representation can leave out some information and/or change to the scientific notation as you can see here :

```
>>> f"{202105.35}"
'202105.35'
>>> f"{202105.35:g}"
'202105'
>>> f"{202105.0}"
'202105.0'
>>> f"{202105.0:g}"
'202105'
```

I want the best of both world with the use of the format parameters but without losing precision.

In my research I found that you can specify a precision with `digit+` but I don't want to set a specific precision but if that's the only way to do it, then I'll have to set one.

Comment: `.rstrip('0.')` perhaps?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel yeah it would work but i'm asking for a solution with fstrings, juste like the :g but that doesn't touch the precision

Comment: So `f"{str(202105.0).rstrip('.0')}"` ?

Comment: This would definitely work i'm not saying the opposite but that's not the solution I am looking for